# create content in https://github.com/username/username/repo without tree/main in path

Tags: html, github, url, jekyll

An error in a recent publication links my code to `https://github.com/username/username/repo` rather than `https://github.com/username/repo`. https://github.com/username/username is my home space. I can put a folder named 'repo' in that directory with an .index file containing a link to the actual location, but the path becomes `https://github.com/username/username/tree/main/repo`. Is there a way to create content at `https://github.com/username/username/repo` without tree/main/ in the path? (my home space site is built with Jekyll, if that helps/complicates anything)

I have also tried creating a submodule of 'repo' in 'https://github.com/username/username', but can't get that path to work out either

Comment: Nope, you can't control what's rendered at `https://github.com/<user>/<user>/repo` - as you note, the branches start with `/tree`, so the closest you could get would be a branch _named_ `repo` at `/<user>/<user>/tree/repo`.

Comment: bummer -- that's what I was afraid of. I was just hoping someone had a brilliant workaround.